# Doctrine Inheritance - Single_Table inheritade from Joined table

Tags: php, symfony, inheritance, doctrine-orm

This is the configuration I want to have:

An Entity "Account" with a JOINED inheritance to two other Entities: "Author" and "AccountBackend".

Then I would want the "AccountBackend" to have a SINGLE_TABLE inheritance with other two Entities: "Administrator" and "FeaturedAuthor". This is the way I have them defined:

Account.php

```
/** 
 * @Entity (repositoryClass="Repositories\Account") 
 * @Table(name="accounts")  
 * @InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="integer")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"1"="Author","2"="AccountBackend"})
 * @HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Account
{
```

Curator.php

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="accounts_author")
 */
class Author extends Account
{
```

AccountBackend.php

```
/** 
 * @Entity (repositoryClass="Repositories\AccountBackend") 
 * @Table(name="accounts_backend")  
 * @InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="integer")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"1"="FeaturedAuthor","2"="Administrator"})
 * @HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class AccountBackend extends Account
{
```

FeaturedAuthor.php

```
/**
 * @Entity
 */
class FeaturedAuthor extends AccountBackend
{
```

Administrator.php

```
/**
 * @Entity
 */
class Administrator extends AccountBackend
{
```

When I have them defined, when I try to do an update through the CLI it says

> "Entity 'Entities\AccountBackend' has to be part of the discriminator
>   map of 'Entities\Account' to be properly mapped in the inheritance
>   hierachy. Alternatively you can make 'Entities\AccountBackend' an
>   abstract class to avoid this exception from occuring."

I don't see anything wrong with the way I defined them, this is the first time that I try to  have inheritance on an already inherited Entity. Any idea of whats wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a case for your "AccountBackend" class in your @DiscriminatorMap

e.g

```
@DiscriminatorMap({"1"="FeaturedAuthor","2"="Administrator", "3"="AccountBackend"})
```

As explain in the [Documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html)

> All entity classes that is part of the mapped entity hierarchy (**including the topmost** class) should be specified in the @DiscriminatorMap. In the case above Person class included.

Comment: Hi. I have that in my Account.php entity

Comment: Yes but your Account entity is not a part of the SINGLE_TABLE inheritance. You need to add AccountBackend to your SINGLE_TABLE's DiscriminatorMap

Answer (score 4):

In case you came here & had problem with *SINGLE_TABLE* inheritance - possible that the problem occurs because your discriminator class is not abstract.

My case example (solution)

```
/**
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="entity", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"product" = "ProductReview", "seller" = "SellerReview"})
 * @ORM\Table(name="reviews")
 */
abstract class Review {}

class ProductReview extends Review {}

class SellerReview extends Review {}
```